# How to display content after product name in Magento Admin

Tags: magento-1.9, php, admin-panel

I want to add additional data after order item name in order view page.

I have added below code in **config.xml** file but it is replace then name. I want to append content not replace.

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="order_items">
        <action method="addColumnRender">
            <column>name</column>
            <block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_name</block>
            <template>productcustomizer/sales/order/view/additional.phtml</template>
        </action> 
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

It is displaying like below

[image]

I want to like below

[image]

I have tried below code in config.xml but it is not working.

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="order_items">
        <block after="content" type="adminhtml/sales_items_column_name" name="additional.product.info" template="productcustomizer/sales/order/view/additional.phtml" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

Answer (score 1):

call your phtml file in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml`

**below**

```
<?php echo $this->getColumnHtml($_item, 'name') ?>
```

Comment: I am developing extension so I can't call like this. if you have any other way Please let me know

Comment: @ChetanKhandla as you are overriding `name` column so you have to call `adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml` in to your template.

Comment: How can I prevent overriding? You have any idea

Comment: Can I call multiple template?

Comment: @ChetanKhandla I dont think there is another way. You can achieve this with the help of javascript without affecting core template file. Where as in your template first jcall core template and then add your content

Comment: How can I add content after block (Append)?

Comment: which content? @ChetanKhandla

Comment: Any content (Like Text, HTML) after or before particulate block.